# Azure Server Database: error: 0 - The wait operation timed out

Tags: azure-sql-database

We use Azure Databases to hold our data for our web app.

All of a sudden as of 8pm Central Time on 10/12/2021, I am seeing this error:

**A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)**

We are seeing this via SQL Server Management Studio and also when I debug within VS 2019.

This doesn't appear to happen with everyone on our team.

Is anyone else seeing issues with Azure database service?

Comment: Hi @tvb2754, the issue you have mentioned could be because of multiple reasons. what is the connection timeout value? what encrypt, certificate options you have selected while making the connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this issue was due to my home network ISP.

I assume the ISP accidently changed a setting for port 1433. I called the ISP, they reconfigured my modem, I rebooted and it still didn't work.

Then about 30 minutes to 45 minutes later, it started working perfect, without any issues within my local debug session in VS 2019 OR with trying to access the Azure database via SSMS.

We also had another developer that was seeing the same issue and he had the same ISP provider since he lives about 15 minutes from me.

All other developers were working fine because they had different ISPs

Answer (score 0):

Ping the Azure SQL database server to get the current IP address of the server.

```
C:\>ping <myserver>.database.windows.net

Pinging data.sn1-1.database.windows.net [65.55.74.144] with 32 bytes of data: Request timed out. Request timed out. Request timed out. Request timed out. Ping statistics for 65.55.74.144: Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)
```

Once you get the IP, run a tracert to find out on what hop the communication gets timed out or has noticeable latency.

```
C:\>tracert 65.55.74.144

Tracing route to 65.55.74.144 over a maximum of 30 hops
1 2 ms 1 ms 1 ms 192.168.0.1
2 6 ms 5 ms 5 ms 10.33.34.50
3 5 ms 4 ms 5 ms 4-1-753.DLLSTX-LCR-07.verizon-gni.net [130.81.107.26]
4 8 ms 5 ms 5 ms so-6-2-0-0.DFW01-BB-RTR1.verizon-gni.net [130.81.28.208]
5 44 ms 43 ms 44 ms so-11-0-0-0.LCC1-RES-BB-RTR1-RE1.verizon-gni.net [130.81.17.40]
6 49 ms 44 ms 44 ms so-6-0-0-0.ASH-PEER-RTR1-re1.verizon-gni.net [130.81.10.90]
```

Sometimes you experience this when you are trying to get connected to SQL Azure using a VPN software on the corporate network, but when you get connected from home you are fine.

Comment: -> I'll try to remember this for next time, Thank you.